# Find the number of months between two dates in decimal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to calculate the number of months between two dates. I want the result in decimal point. For example, if my date range is "2017-02-01" to "2017-03-1", then I am expecting the number of months to be something like **1.033** in decimal.

Please help.

Comment: How did you come to that result?

Comment: What is 0.033 of a month based on? Are you assuming 30-day months? What happens during Daylight Saving when a day might be 23 or 25 hours long?

Comment: It seems like you're expecting that difference to come to 1 day over 1 month, but it should evaluate as exactly 1 month, and your decimal for 1 day is based on a 30 day month while your example is a 28 or 29 day month

Comment: FYI, an English sentence starts with a capital letter.

Comment: 1.033 is not the actual result but what i want is result in decimal. because "2017-02-01" to "2017-02-28" becomes 1 month and still there is one more day left. so i am expecting result in decimal instead of 1 month

Comment: For me, one day left means less than 1. Something like this `(Date.new(2017,2,1)..Date.new(2017,3,1)).count / 30.0`. it's like 0.9something

Comment: Ok, I'm just saying that you should probably expect the difference between those two dates to be 1.0 month, not 1.0 month plus 1 day

Comment: There's always the [TimeDifference gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/time_difference): `TimeDifference.between(start_time, end_time).in_months`

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do something like this

```
#Mondel.time_diff_in_months("2017-03-01", "2017-02-01")
def time_diff_in_months(grater_date, lesser_date)
  Time.at(grater_date.to_time - lesser_date.to_time).month # 1
end
```

I hope that this helps

Comment: I want result in decimal because "2017-02-01" to "2017-02-28" becomes 1 month and there is one more day left of march month so result is not exactly 1 month. result should be in decima

Comment: What is 100% of 1 month is it 28 days, is it 30, 31?

Comment: In case what @MZaragoza is saying isn't clear. Month is not a fixed 'unit'. Making it a decimal place will be problematic. You can't safely do anything with `1.033 months` unless you know exactly which days are in question which defeats the purpose of having it.

Comment: i don't think this works if the difference is beyond 12 months. It will still give you the difference as if it is within a calendar year.